# How to create a moving background using accelerometer in Android - Parallax effect

Tags: android, parallax

I want to add a moving background to my application, for now with only one moving layer, then I will scale it to more layers if needed. The desired effect should looks like this [example 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B2i4EA-4gq0)  or [example 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=429kM-yXGz8) . Can someone point me to the right direction? For now I'm trying to implement the suggestions found [here](http://vitiy.info/how-to-create-parallax-effect-using-accelerometer/).

Comment: P.S. the app is a normal app, I don't use Unity or other engines inside.

Comment: So what's stopping you? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have the data from accelerometer but I don't know how to move/shift the background based on it.